# Exported FBX appears transparent in Unity

Tags: materials, transparency, unity, geometry, visibility

I'm trying to export an FBX into Unity. In blender, the materials are opaque and have no transparency. However, when I export it into Unity, the object appears transparent.

I have made sure to recalculate my normals using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, as well as apply location scale and rotation using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Here's an image. If anybody has any ideas as to what is going wrong, I would appreciate it.

[image: Blender on left, Unity on right]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Even when changing all of the Unity materials to the default, I still end up with the large transparent gaps in the big gray building. Maybe the issue isn't material related after all.

Comment: Is it possible that your normals are flipped?

Comment: i've had this problem when using Principled BSDF.. if I switch to Diffuse BSDF in blender materials, then this doesn't happen. not sure if this is a bug in blender FBX export of P-BSDF, or whether unity isn't handling something in FBX correctly

Comment: So , enable backface culling option in blender , now u can see the exact problem in blender as in unity , recalculate the normals there , this video will help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmMD9fV98Co maybe in diffuse bsdf light data is abble read from both sides thats why u r able to succeed in diffuse bsdf